# Does 1言語1章ずつ imply that each chapter is in a different language?

Tags: translation

I'm reading about a [Japanese book approaching linguistics and translation](http://www.tufs.ac.jp/NEWS/notice/21040701_2.html) through the lens of "The Little Prince" by Antoine de Saint-Exupéry. A sentence in the press release announcing the book reads:

> 第2部は28言語の概説に続いて、『星の王子さま』を1言語1章ずつ読み進みます。
> The second part reads through "The Little Prince", one language per chapter, covering an outline of 28 languages.

The part I'm unsure about is how to interpret 1言語1章ずつ -- does this necessarily imply that each chapter of The Little Prince is translated into a different language? Or is each chapter a complete translation of the work into each of the 28 languages? Or is it ambiguous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it means each chapter of the story is translated into a different language, because of:

> 世界の名作を世界の言語で**リレーする**
> **『星の王子さま』を**1言語1章ずつ**読み進みます**。

「リレーする」「『星の王子さま』を読み進みます」という表現から、一つの物語を最初から最後まで通して読むという感じがします。

So I think it would be something like 英語で『星の王子さま』の第1章を読み、ドイツ語で『星の王子さま』の第2章を読み...

Comment: 『星の王子さま』の原作って、27章までですかね？